# SQL List Products that are Not Already Ordered

Tags: mysql, left-join, isnull

I have a situation where a LEFT JOIN is not going far enough in what I need to accomplish.  I have a product table (**Products with columns ItemID, ProductName, Price**) and an order table (**Orders with columns OrderNumber, ItemID, Quantity**).

I need the query to return all of the products from the Products table that are not currently a part of a specific order (for example, list all products that are not a part of OrderNumber 52).

My current query lists all of the products but excludes the products that are a part of ANY OrderNumber.

```
$query = "SELECT Products.ItemID, Products.ProductName
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Orders.ItemID = Products.ItemID
WHERE Orders.ItemID IS NULL
ORDER BY Products.ProductName";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a anti-join for this purpose, like so:

```
SELECT ItemID, ProductName
FROM Products
WHERE ItemID NOT IN (
    SELECT ItemID
    FROM Orders
    WHERE OrderID = X
)
ORDER BY ProductName
```

Comment: the anti-join code is simple and effective. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Products.ItemID, Products.ProductName
FROM Products
WHERE Products.ItemID not in (select Orders.ItemID from Orders where Orders.OrderNumber = xxx)
ORDER BY Products.ProductName
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need can be easily accomplished just by adding the order number in the join condition:

```
SELECT Products.ItemID, Products.ProductName
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON (Orders.ItemID = Products.ItemID AND OrderNumber = 52)
WHERE Orders.ItemID IS NULL
ORDER BY Products.ProductName
```